# CSS Tabbed Layout

Tags: html, css, layout

Pretend I have the following html and css

```css
h1{
    color: rgb(61, 133, 200);
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}

h1 ~ *:not(h1) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

h2{
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-left: 40px !important;
}

h2 ~ *:not(h2) {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

h3{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin-left: 80px !important;
}

h2 ~ *:not(h2) {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello First</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph that I wrote that belongs to p</p>
<p>This paragraph should also belong to the first p</p>

  <h2>Tabbed</h2>
  <p>I want this paragraph to be tabbed directly</p>
  <p>This paragrah should be tabbed too<p>

    <h3>Tabbed</h3>
    <p>This should be more tabbed</p>
    <p>This paragrah should be more tabbed too<p>

    
  <h2>More Tabby</h2>
  <p>This should be single tabbed</p>
  <p>How tabby<p>
    
    
<h1>Return of The Title</h1>
<p> This should no longer be tabbed </p>
<p> Nor should this <p>
```

I would like to apply a css style that matches what is referenced in the code. This is proving relatively difficult, and I'm having to use the dreaded important tags. Note that I may have anything below the h1, and I would also like it to have the same margin.

Can anybody suggest ways to achieve this?

Comment: Can you change the HTMl as well, or only the CSS?

Comment: No the html can't change. It's basically the output of a markdown converter :P

Answer (score 0):

you can use **:active** selector to style select and style the active link.A link becomes active when you click on it.

I'm added an example with `background-color` .

```css
h1{
    color: rgb(61, 133, 200);
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}

h1 ~ *:not(h1) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

h2{
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-left: 40px !important;
}

h2 ~ *:not(h2) {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

h3{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin-left: 80px !important;
}

h2 ~ *:not(h2) {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
p:active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
h3:active {
  background-color: red;
  }
h1:active {
  background-color: red;
  }
h2:active {
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Hello First</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph that I wrote that belongs to p</p>
<p>This paragraph should also belong to the first p</p>

  <h2>Tabbed</h2>
  <p>I want this paragraph to be tabbed directly</p>
  <p>This paragrah should be tabbed too<p>

    <h3>Tabbed</h3>
    <p>This should be more tabbed</p>
    <p>This paragrah should be more tabbed too<p>

    
  <h2>More Tabby</h2>
  <p>This should be single tabbed</p>
  <p>How tabby<p>
    
    
<h1>Return of The Title</h1>
<p> This should no longer be tabbed </p>
<p> Nor should this <p>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question though. I want the <p> tag below the h3 for example to have the same indentation level as the h3 tag itself. Also, the last two <p> tags should have the same indentation level as the <h1> tag